# Remove path on Htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite a link with an htaccess file but I don't know how to do this with this kind of rule

the thing is that some links have this path `domain.com/sub1/sub2/file.html`

and I want to remove "sub1" and take "sub2" only. for example `domain.com/sub2/file.html`

but this problem is not on all links, so I want to write an "if" statement to whenever that "sub1" is there, eliminate it.

is this possible?

Comment: By "remove" you mean to redirect the browser to the link without the "sub1" or internally rewrite the request to a resource without the "sub1"?

Comment: rewrite the request without "sub1"

Comment: Is `/sub2/` always there after `/sub1/` or it can change?

Comment: it can change... I just want to remove "sub1" whenever it is there

Comment: (Off-topic) Hi Diego. Today [you asked about using cURL to access Mailgun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438711/how-to-use-curl-on-the-command-line-to-call-the-mailgun-api), but deleted the question after it acquired downvotes. I would encourage you to improve the question and to re-publish it, in particular showing what you have tried from the online manual and where you find yourself stuck. Whilst it is not always ideally expressed, the suggestion to include code and demonstrate prior effort is a good one, I believe.